# Pinging multiple vms on local network: destination host unreachable

Tags: linux, unix, centos, vagrant, vagrantfile

While doing a vprofile project in linux setting up a multiple vm through hypervisor and a vagrant file i'm facing issues as all vms can't ping to each other as required in the stack.

PING web01 (192.168.56.11) 56(84) bytes of data.
From localhost.localdomain (192.168.56.107) icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From localhost.localdomain (192.168.56.107) icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From localhost.localdomain (192.168.56.107) icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From localhost.localdomain (192.168.56.107) icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable

what should i do? here they're able to ping to each other

Comment: If VMs using mactap driver they cant interact.

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). **Vagrant is specifically off topic.** Please delete this and ask, instead, on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or, in this case, https://askubuntu.com/ or https://superuser.com/

Comment: I encountered a similar technical issue whereby web01 was running on 'ubuntu/jammy64', while other virtual machines (VMs) were on 'eurolinux-vagrant/centos-stream-9'. Despite being able to connect to all other VMs, connectivity to web01 was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

If VMs using mactap driver they cant interact. Each other and to host. You need to create bridge network

Comment: The question is off topic. Do not answer off topic questions. [answer]